# Flutter Firestore querying with docs and collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore db and a flutter app. The database is like the following:

```
Collection    Doc                   Collection
scans         uid:DateTime.now()    userID: 'abjnbj28snOPEAJd', scanID: 'test', data: 'abc', company: 'TH'
              uid:DateTime.now()    userID: 'nj12djaJDJaihinf', scanID: 'test2', data: 'xyz', company: 'PH'
```

The reason for me not storing data inside a doc in the users collection is that I need the admin of the company to be able to access all scans regardless of which user scanned according to the company name.
The reason for me using uid:DateTime.now() is that each doc (scan) should be unique.

Questions:

1. Is this the best approach for dealing with data that needs to be referred to?
2. Is using the uid:DateTime.now() best approach for document ID? It needs to be very unique, earlier I was using DateTime.now() only as scanID under users/uid/scans/DateTime/scanData.
3. How do I query these scans and filter by userID, company, or scanID?

This is how I'm doing it now, which results in different kinds of errors:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('scans')
              .orderBy('dateTime', descending: true)
              .limit(10)
              .where('userID', isEqualTo: user.uid)
              .get()
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
              print(snapshot.data['userID'];
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the user id as a document id, then to filter by user id, you can do the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('scans')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .get()
```

To filter by company, you can use a `where` clause:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('scans')
              .where('company', isEqualTo: 'TH')
              .get()
```

Comment: I tried this, but its showing me error: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.

Comment: you have to do the following `querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        print(result.data());
      });`, the class querySnapshot has a field called `docs` to loop inside all the documents in the collection

Comment: In a future builder?